# My swiper doesn't have momentum for the first 3 swipes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, swiper.js

This is an odd issue I haven't been able to fix. For some reason when I do the first few swipes on my swiper it teleports to whatever slide I released on instantly, instead of having momentum. It creates a pretty ugly effect. My options are pretty simple so I dont know what could be causing this. After the first few swipes it works perfectly until I refresh.

The website is https://instabrewdevelopment.myshopify.com/ and the swipers are the ones in the left mobile navigation panel. Since it's in css mode you have to test it with touch instead of mouse unfortunately.

My settings go as follows:

```
function navCarouselSettings(el){
        
  el.removeClass();
  el.addClass('swiper');
        
  new Swiper(el[0], {
    spaceBetween: 12,
    cssMode: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto'         
  });
        
}
```

Some other css changes I made:

```
.mobileNavBar .swiper {
    overflow: visible;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  
  .mobileNavBar .swiper-wrapper {
    scroll-padding-left: 18px;
    scroll-padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 8px;
  }
```

I'm not sure how these could cause it but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure it out. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated!

Ive tried using threshold, removing some of my css properties, and a few other small things with no luck.